# Nomenclature for largest odd factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology

Is there a standard phrase for the largest odd factor of a positive integer $n$, or more generally for $n$ divided by the largest power of $p$ that divides it (with $p$ some fixed prime)? Five minutes of online search failed to yield an answer.

(I’m hoping for an answer to my terminology question, but general advice about how to find this sort of information on my own would be appreciated as well. I hate to clutter up MathOverflow with questions that I could answer for myself if I knew how to search the internet more intelligently.)

Comment: It is called the $2$-free part of $n$.  More generally, the $p$-free part of $n$ is $n$ divided by the highest power of $p$ that's a factor of $n$.

Comment: I think "odd part" is also common; see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPart.html, or https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/arith/misc.html#sage.arith.misc.odd_part.

Comment: @KConrad: Thanks! Yours is the answer I was looking for.  If you post it as an answer rather than a comment I'll approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call it the $2$-free part of $n$ or the odd part of $n$.  For a general prime $p$, the $p$-free part of $n$ is what you have after you divide $n$ by the highest power of $p$ dividing it.

Comment: ... and, again, complementarily, for prime $p$, the $p$-part of an integer is the largest power of $p$ dividing it.